# Convert specific symbols to lating

Tags: c#

I'm beginner in C# and I have a task to create program where user can input latvian symbol and then this symbol converted to latin

```
Console.Write("Please enter some text:");
    string text = Console.ReadLine();

    Dictionary<string, string> vocabulary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    vocabulary.Add("Ā", "Aa");
    vocabulary.Add("Č", "Ch");
    vocabulary.Add("Ē", "Ee");
    vocabulary.Add("Ģ", "G'");
    vocabulary.Add("Ī", "Ii");
    vocabulary.Add("Ķ", "K'");
    vocabulary.Add("Ļ", "L'");
    vocabulary.Add("Ņ", "N'");
    vocabulary.Add("Š", "Sh");
    vocabulary.Add("Ū", "Uu");
    vocabulary.Add("Ž", "Zh");
    vocabulary.Add("ā", "aa");
    vocabulary.Add("č", "ch");
    vocabulary.Add("ē", "ee");
    vocabulary.Add("ģ", "g'");
    vocabulary.Add("ī", "ii");
    vocabulary.Add("ķ", "k'");
    vocabulary.Add("ļ", "l'");
    vocabulary.Add("ņ", "n'");
    vocabulary.Add("š", "sh");
    vocabulary.Add("ū", "uu");
    vocabulary.Add("ž", "zh");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in vocabulary)
    {
        if (text.Contains(item.Key))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Converted to chat language: " + item.Value + text);
        } 
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Converted to chat language: " + text);
```

How to encoding dictionary key?

Comment: Q: You want to convert "text", correct?  Then you need your foreach loop to process "text" (a character at a time), don't you?

Comment: Incidentally, you might need to use `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;` to get it to read the input properly.

Comment: For example, if the user writes Ābols, then Aabols, Fūrtoļ - Fuurtol'should come out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to replace keys, with values for each item in dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in vocabulary)
{
    text = text.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it outputs just Abols and etc, But I need to he replaced the letter and gave Aabols

Comment: @ᗩᖱᖆᓲᗅᘘᑸᕩᖶᖇᓎᕓ obviously something is not quite as it is in your question because replacing `"Ā"` with ` "Aa"` in `Ābols` would abviously result in `Aabols`. may be your text is just `Abols` and not `Ābols`, so actually no replacements happen?